# python installation - what version I've installed (Mac installation)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I've installed python and while checking to see which version I've installed, it seems I have 2 versions installed

I was running this command

```
which -a python python3
```

then I got this result

```
/usr/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

Is it correct? I was doing something wrong? I'm confused because also while running this command

```
python --version
```

I'm getting

```
Python 2.7.16
```

Comment: `python` on your system means Python 2. If you want to run Python 3, use `python3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

in the python console. That way you could know for sure what version you are actually using

Answer (score 0):

It is correct. You have python 2 installed in your mac

Answer (score 0):

You can try python3 --version to see python 3 version installed.

Answer (score 0):

by default mac os  comes up with python 2 preinstalled
while you only need to install python 3